# ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found

Tags: python

I'm on a Linux machine without root access.  I built my own local copy of openssl and python (2.7.13).  When I try to import hashlib in python, I get these error messages:

```
> python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 22 2017, 19:23:53)
[GCC Intel(R) C++ gcc 4.8 mode] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
```

UPDATE: I just realized that the python build failed to build the hashlib module:

```
building '_hashlib' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/p/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/include -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/lo
cal/include -I/p/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/Include -I/p/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13 -c /p/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/Modules/_hashopenssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x8
6_64-2.7/p/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/Modules/_hashopenssl.o
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:74:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:960,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:98,
                 from /p/home/user_jp/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/Modules/_hashopenssl.c:39:
/p/home/apps/gmpapp/gcc_dir/platform/gcc-4.8.4/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.4/include-fixed/openssl/bn.h:610:1: error: unknown type name 'CRYPTO_THREADID'
 CRYPTO_THREADID *BN_BLINDING_thread_id(BN_BLINDING *);
 ^
```

How should I fix this?  It looks like the problem might be that it's looking for the openssl headers in /usr/include/openssl, but I'm trying to use my own installation of openssl.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this as one of the first of a host of errors when using [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) in vim on OSX. This was after migrating from one Mac to another using the Migration Assistant, so I wasn't doing a fresh install. In my case it was because the Anaconda python distribution was messing with Homebrew.

As `brew doctor` warned me, Anaconda can cause problems for Homebrew. So I removed the part of my path that included `anaconda` and then ran:

```
brew uninstall macvim
brew install macvim
brew linkapps
```

Homebrew complained that `brew linkapps` is not a good command, but it worked for me all the same, and my vim errors went away.

Comment: `brew linkapps` has been deprecated since around January 2017: Unfortunately brew linkapps cannot behave nicely with e.g. Spotlight using either aliases or symlinks and Homebrew formulae do not build "proper" .app bundles that can be relocated. Instead, please consider using brew cask and migrate formulae using .apps to casks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue on Ubuntu 16.04. Turns out I needed the package `libssl-dev`.

(ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The python build scripts were looking in `/usr/include` for the openssl header files.  Since I installed my own local version of openssl, those header files were wrong.

So, I set `CFLAGS` to `-i/location/correct/openssl/header/files` and did a `make distclean` and configure, and build and it worked.