# "ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found" when using any hg mercurial commands

Tags: python, macos, openssl, mercurial, homebrew

When trying to use any `hg` Mercurial commands on the console, I keep getting this error. 
I installed Python using Homebrew and I am running Mac OS Catalina v. 10.15.1.

Any reference would be appreciated. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
hg commit --amend
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 43, in <module>
    dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgdemandimport/demandimportpy2.py", line 150, in __getattr__
    self._load()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgdemandimport/demandimportpy2.py", line 94, in _load
    _origimport, head, globals, locals, None, level)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgdemandimport/demandimportpy2.py", line 43, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 625, in <module>
    class lazyaliasentry(object):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 636, in lazyaliasentry
    @util.propertycache
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgdemandimport/demandimportpy2.py", line 150, in __getattr__
    self._load()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgdemandimport/demandimportpy2.py", line 94, in _load
    _origimport, head, globals, locals, None, level)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgdemandimport/demandimportpy2.py", line 43, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 180, in <module>
    'md5': hashlib.md5,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hgdemandimport/demandimportpy2.py", line 151, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._module, attr)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'md5'
```

I also tried following the instruction on this issue but none of the solutions seem to work

```
brew link openssl --force
Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: Your link to issue 1 is missing.

Comment: This sounds like a Python issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399331/error-importing-hashlib-with-python-2-7-but-not-with-2-6  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798118/errorrootcode-for-hash-md5-was-not-found

Comment: Any solutions for MacOS? I did try these solutions but none of them are working. I keep getting the same error. When I try to link openssl as i pasted in my question I get the error pasted there. I also tried running these 4 commands but nothing happened: 
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

Comment: Strangely enough I had the same issue with YCM in Macvim and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61598827/3383878) solved my problem.

Answer (score 713, accepted):

Running `brew reinstall python@2` didn't work for my existing Python 2.7 virtual environments. Inside them there were still `ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found` errors.

I encountered this problem after I ran `brew upgrade openssl`. And here's the fix:

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/openssl
```

...which shows

```
1.0.2t
```

According to the existing version, run:

```
$ brew switch openssl 1.0.2t
```

...which shows

```
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t
Opt link created for /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t
```

After that, run the following command in a Python 2.7 virtualenv:

```
(my-venv) $ python -c "import hashlib;m=hashlib.md5();print(m.hexdigest())"
```

...which shows

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

No more errors.

Comment: This helped me on a mac catalina update or maybe the bash -> zsh where tons of things like this were broken.

Comment: I didn't have 1.0.2q but doing the same with 1.0.2r also worked

Comment: Thanks, I would never have figured that out. I had this problem after trying to install pipx via homebrew

Comment: Yes.  This works for me.  I have spent days on this and in fear of having to re-image my machine.  I'd tried to reinstall python@2 numerous time but still could not fix the problem.  This one definitely works.  MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Flawless steps.

Comment: This helped me too, but my homebrew claimed I had 1.1.1f installed for openssl when trying "brew upgrade openssl". However, switching to the latest 1.0.x version I had allowed me to proceed.

Comment: running brew switch openssl [version] did it for me, didn't need last command

Comment: @FlorentRoques that's because you would have had the same version as the example. In my case `ls /usr/local/Cellar/openssl` returned `1.0.2s` so I needed to run `brew switch openssl 1.0.2s`

Comment: works had 2 openssl installations in brew which I needed to compile something ellse

Comment: Wow Wow Wow! :-)

Comment: Thank you! I have both 1.0.2q and 1.0.2r in folder, and did the step for 1.0.2q. It works!

Comment: Can you explain a bit what `brew switch` do? I tried your solution and everything works now, but when I run `openssl version` command it still shows I am using LibreSSL 2.6.5. I am confused about how python picks up openssl 1.0.2 instead of LibreSSL in my system @Rockallite

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal! Clearly laying out the steps here is really helpful. It was `1.0.2s` for me :)

Comment: Thanks! This problem occured in my Zshell on 10.15.4. I checked openssl which is 1.0.2s on my machine and `brew switch openssl 1.0.2s` did the job.

Comment: Thank you vvvvvery much ! I met this error when i run `gclient sync`. The openssl on my Mac is 1.0.2s. So i run `brew switch openssl 1.0.2s`.

Comment: I want to give a medal to this guy. Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: Third time in a few months I am saved by this! :'D

Comment: Uninstalling python, and then clearing the `pyenv` directory seemed to solve it for me.
 `rm -R ~/.pyenv`

Comment: So Now with the installation of zsh and Calalina there is no `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl` what's a 2.7 junkie to do?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, but this worked with 1.0.2q! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I got this error after the macOS update. Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Any way to double up-vote this? I saw the same as @quozqzzu; 1.0.2s. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me, in my case `openssl` version was `1.1.1h`, so command to fix was `brew switch openssl 1.1.1h`

Comment: `brew switch` was removed https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/339

Comment: Following the reinstall instructions in the answer on this SO post:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298514/how-to-reinstall-python2-from-homebrew)  , along with reinstall of openssl@1.1 worked to get me past these hashlib errors.

Comment: In the absence of `brew switch`, and a missing `1.0.2t` locally for me, I used `brew install openssl@1.0`, which installed `1.0.2t`. You might need to `brew tap rbenv/tap` to get the recipe. After this I need to add openssl 1.0 to my path. For me, this was `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: It's freaking me out, not working for me on MacOS

Answer (score 101):

Managed to fix this by first unlinking openssl

```
brew unlink openssl
```

And then [reinstalling python](https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/540#issuecomment-565536952)

```
brew reinstall python@2
```

I also noticed that when running 'brew doctor' there was a warning related to an openssl folder found in /usr/local/include/node/. I deleted this folder before running the above commands (not sure if related)

Comment: I didn't have openssl linked but reinstalling python did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had to relink the azure-cli with brew

Comment: As of Feb. 10, 2020, python@2 is removed from homebrew and this answer will not work. See the above answer by @Rockallite, which worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Paul , I marked the above answer as the correct one

Answer (score 53):

The case for me is that when I install dependencies of a django web app, it  messes up the environment. When I type `cd`, it shows the same error.

The problem was the `openssl` library, it can not find the correct ones.

If you are on Macintosh, you can type

`ls /usr/local/Cellar/openssl`

to see all the versions,

`brew switch openssl 1.0.XXXX`

to choose the available openssl version.

Then the error is gone :)

Comment: one liner```bash ls /usr/local/Cellar/openssl | xargs brew switch openssl```

Comment: Worked after I used @poca 's answer and then above answer

Comment: Thanks so much, you're a lifesaver - this finally worked after fighting with it for over an hour.

Answer (score 39):

Just uninstall python2

`$ brew uninstall python@2`

If there is any error :

`$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@2`

Comment: I laughed but as a warning to noobs- don't do this.

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS 

Answer (score 6):

My problem was having `pyenv` installed and pointing to an old python 2 version

Uninstall python@2 (python2 was EOL since Jan 1st, 2020)

```
$ brew uninstall python@2
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1... (4,169 files, 76.0MB)
```

then

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.12 (set by /Users/admin/.python-version)
  3.4.5
  3.7.7

$ pyenv local system
$ pyenv global system
```

Comment: A bit late in the game, but thank you, your solution works perfectly!

Comment: This worked great for me! thank you. I spent a lot of time installing things and this took just two seconds 

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue recently (2020, May) with Google's GCP CLI.  It also works on the obsolete Python 2.7.

This is a borked Python 2 installation problem. mBrew no longer correctly installs Python 2 gracefully, as no one cares about abondonware.

Conda still installs Python 2 in an environment; I did that.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was multiple versions of python installed (python was still aliased to python2 but i wanted pip to use python3). i also have a `python3` bin installed on my system

```bash
$ python -V
Python 2

# use pip with python3
$ python3 -m pip install fish
```

see [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip) for details

Comment: This fixed my issue, I had multiple python versions

Answer (score 3):

The next solution worked for me on MacOS Catalina:

1. Unlink openssl

```sh
brew unlink openssl
```

2. Reinstall python 2.7 (removed from homebrew and can't be installed via `brew install python@2`)

```sh
brew tap-new <user>/homebrew-python2
brew extract python@2 <user>/homebrew-python2
brew reinstall /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/<user>/homebrew-python2/Formula/python@2.7.17.rbl
```

Comment: I did the same but instead step 2) I did `brew remove python@2` :) macOS Catalina ships Python 2.7 built-in and it seemed less issue prone then to rely on that directly. To me python support via brew seemed to always cause some issue somewhere in that past xD

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I just reinstall python2 using `pyenv`

```
pyenv uninstall 2.7.18
pyenv install 2.7.18
```

then everything seems to hooks up.

Answer (score 0):

When I would import hashlib I would see an error message stating that hash md5 was not found.

I was able to fix this problem by first unlinking openssl:
brew unlink openssl

Then I uninstalled python 2.7 using MacPorts:
sudo port uninstall python27

Then I installed python 2.7 using MacPorts:
sudo port install python27

Now importing hashlib works :)

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Mojave (10.14.6), this worked for me:

- Save the [file](https://gist.github.com/debodirno/91f713c4755fd1f05c530061f6269989) as python@2.rb in your current directory.
- brew reinstall python@2.rb
- I was using virtual environments, so I had to link them back to `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/pip` for `python` and `pip` binaries.

Answer (score 0):

After installing `openssl` I got the same problem. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59816812/3960038) didn't help me, but after manual linking of `libcrypto.1.1.dylib` and `libssl.1.1.dylib` everything start working. In my case it was:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my environment was using python 2.7.15. When I switched my pyenv version to 2.7.18 it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me, I use port not brew:

`sudo port upgrade openssl`

Answer (score 0):

**One reason: an older libssl is needed**

When this error occurs, Python is not able to import the _hashlib.py module. One reason for this is libssl changing its ABI during version transition. This affects at least Python2.7.

**Solution:** Download [libssl version 1.1.0](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.0/), compile and install it in a different location. Then tell python during its configure process to use this old libssl library.

For me a non standard prefix like *./configure --prefix=/home/anyuser/python* for the python code tree was sufficient (i installed libssl to /usr/local), as the parallel installed old libssl library in a usual place (/usr/local) was automatically found and used during the configuration and compile process.

This is a good example for why having /usr and /usr/local directories in parallel. I always wondered about that. /usr for the standard system stuff, /usr/local for additional parallel things.

After compiling python2.7 there appears a summary in the terminal where it tells you what went wrong during compilaton/linking. There should be no sign of a missed _hashlib anymore.