# ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found. Error in npm install

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, npm, webpack

I have found a few similar questions with title tag - `ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found` - in StackOverflow, but I couldn't relate it with the issue which I am facing at this moment during npm installation.

I'm on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6)

with node version `v8.0.0` & npm `v5.0.0`

I am getting the following error message while trying to install Webpack into my project.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-dev-server webpack-cli

> node-gyp rebuild

ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):

ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
```

I have tried to switch my node & npm versions into v12.0.0 and v6.9.0 respectively, but it follows the same error.

Does anyone have any idea about it? How to resolve this issue? I feel it should be more of a config, rather than a specific package installation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Additional  info:

I am running on `python version: 2.7.16`

Update:

I have just observed that the same error follows with all npm installation in my system.

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269208/errorrootcode-for-hash-md5-was-not-found-not-able-to-use-any-hg-mercurial-co) & workaround given along with it introduced a different error into the stack :

```
> node-gyp rebuild

  xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

  xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

  xcode_version, _ = XcodeVersion()
  File"/Users/arunkramachandran/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1265, in XcodeVersion
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found - not able to use any hg mercurial commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269208/errorrootcode-for-hash-md5-was-not-found-not-able-to-use-any-hg-mercurial-co)

Comment: @RaekhVoid Nope. In fact, that introduced an additional error to my installation stack now. I have updated the question with the new error message. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: I had similar issue, below link solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269208/errorrootcode-for-hash-md5-was-not-found-when-using-any-hg-mercurial-command

Answer (score 14):

What happens then if you follow this fix? [node-gyp issues](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569)

**Edit**: Editing this according to Blackfurnace's advice.

If the problem you're having is related to node-gyp, the following commands should fix it :

> ```
> xcode-select --install # Install Command Line Tools if you haven't already.
> sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools # Enable command line tools
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed after running

```
brew upgrade openssl
```

Follow the answer here : ["ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found" when using any hg mercurial commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269208/errorrootcode-for-hash-md5-was-not-found-when-using-any-hg-mercurial-command)