# A python3 virtualenv and am trying to create Django project. I see "ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found" with python2.7 mentioned in the error?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv with `python3 -m venv env`, 
activated `env`. `which python` and `python --version` confirm my environment is active and running `Python 3.6.1`. I then went to install django with `pip install django`. Then     `django-admin startproject project` this command creates a the project but returns the following:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
```

I then ran

```
cd project
django-admin startapp account
```

Same thing, created the app but returned this same error/warning.

I notice that `python2.7` shows up a lot in this error. When I activate `env` and enter the interactive console it shows it running python 3.6, not sure what is going on here. These commands are doing what they are supposed to but throwing this error, so not even sure if it is something I should worry about? Thanks for any help.

Edit: I feel like I have created python3 virtual environments and set up django projects without an issue many times. Recently deployed my first project and am thinking maybe I could have screwed something up on my machine? I see other questions related to this error referring to `ssl`...
I tried `brew unlink openssl` as recommended here [ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found - not able to use any hg mercurial commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269208/errorrootcode-for-hash-md5-was-not-found-not-able-to-use-any-hg-mercurial-co) but that did not work.

Lastly sorry for the poorly worded title I had to try and convey the problem in 150 characters.

Comment: `which python` will show you if `source env/bin/activate` has worked.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison did not know this but it returns `/Users/justin/Desktop/social/env/bin/python` so it using the environment

Comment: `python --version` will confirm what version of python you have 
 activated

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison `Python 3.6.1`... seems this error is all over the internet. None of the solutions I've seen have helped but looks like a python issue not a django issue?

Comment: Strange. try using pip3 explicitly if `pip3 --version` shows the correct path.

Comment: I used pip3 explicitly to globally install certbot to get around an openssl issue this week.

Comment: You could try updating python3 as well. I'm on 3.7.6. The latest is 3.8.2.

Comment: That returned  `pip 20.0.2 from /Users/justin/Desktop/social/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip` . Tried creatring a new env/project using pip3, no effect. Will try upgrading python, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I just got similar errors with `virtualenv -p python3 env-test-for-justin` but django installed with `source env-test-for-justin/bin/activtate` and `pip install django` with no issues.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison I'm confused on what you are saying. You got a similar error, but django installed regardless?

Comment: Yes. Django works.

Answer (score 2):

python@2.7 is no longer supported by brew.

I got rid of the error message by removing the brew python 2.7 and then installing virtualenv with sudo pip3.

**Note this will cause issues with any legacy projects on your device that uses brew python 2.7 virtual environments.**

```sh
brew uninstall python@2.7
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with creating a new environment.

However ... installing django worked.

```sh
csmu:test-for-justin admin$ virtualenv -p python3 env-test-for-justin
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Already using interpreter /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/admin/source/test-for-justin/env-test-for-justin/bin/python3.7
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/admin/source/test-for-justin/env-test-for-justin/bin/python (you must use /Users/admin/source/test-for-justin/env-test-for-justin/bin/python3.7)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

```sh
source env-test-for-justin/bin/activate

pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-3.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting asgiref~=3.2
  Using cached asgiref-3.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, pytz, asgiref, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.2.3 django-3.0.4 pytz-2019.3 sqlparse-0.3.1

django-admin startproject api .

./manage.py migrate
(env-test-for-justin) csmu:test-for-justin admin$ ./manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 05, 2020 - 00:56:19
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'api.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```